# UIPanGesture does not scroll parent UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

Layout situation:

I have a UICollectionView with multiple cells (arranged as a pager).
A cell contains a full size UIScrollView (A) with content size is equal to it's frame size.
This scroll view contains a second UIScrollView (B) with a content size larger then its frame size, means it is scrollable.

The problem is that a UIPanGesture issued in the inner scroll view (B) does not issue paging on the UICollectionView when the pan gesture hits the bounds of the inner scroll view (B).
I already figured out that this is because of the scroll view (A) is not scrollable because its frame size equals the content size.

**Any idea how to achieve paging/scrolling on the collection view when a pan gesture is issued on the inner scroll view (B)?**

I cannot replace the scroll view (A) as the scroll view is needed when the device is rotated.

```
        UICollectionViewCell
------------------------------------------------------------
       |  -----------------------------------  |
       | | UIScrollView (A)                  | |
       | | (ContentSize = FrameSize)         | |
       | |                                   | |
       | |  -------------------------------  | |
       | | | UIScrollView (B)              | | |
       | | | (ContentSize = FrameSize * 2) | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | | |                               | | |
       | |  -------------------------------  | |
       | |                                   | |
       | |                                   | |
       |  -----------------------------------  |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using scrollviews instead of other CV/TV 's ? I know it works by default having a CV inside a CV. (CollectionView)

Comment: It is not good practice to use UIScrollView inside UIScrollView in same direction. But you can set the delegate of UIScrollView and listen to the offset and scroll the view you want.